# Addition of Value Stored in Variable in a Loop

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a foreach loop. which has a variable. how to Add variable values in a single variable.

```
$sal = "";
foreach($variable as $key => $value){
   $sal= $value->Salary;
}
echo $sal;
```

Comment: What you want to get?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
$sal = 0;
foreach($variable as $key => $value){
   $sal += $value->Salary;
}
echo $sal;
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you're referring to concatenation, since you instantiate `$sal = ""` (as a string). Use the [concatenating assignment operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php).

```
$sal = "";
foreach($variable as $key => $value){
   $sal .= $value->Salary;
}
echo $sal;
```

Answer (score 0):

IMO, use `array_map()`

```
$sal=0;
$sal = array_sum(array_map(
                 function($item){
                     return $item->Salary;
                 }, 
       $variable));
```